# how can I add a new <a> with jquery when the <a> is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="links">
<a href="#">#1</a>
</div>
```

so when I click on the anchor tag I want it to add a new anchor tag with jquery. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Where did you want to put this new `<a>` element? With what text? What `href`? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: For example, should it add the new anchor tag to the div? And should new  `<a>` also be used for adding new anchors, and if so what is the purpose of using links in the first place?

Comment: I want it so that it will multiply the <a href="#">#1</a> but make the 1 a 2 and then 2 a 3 and so forth

Comment: Then [edit] you question to clarify your requirements, because that's the sort of detail that should be immediately available to those trying to help you. What should happen if the user clicks link 1 twice? Should that generate a new link 2, or should it add link 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest, given the lack of information in the question itself:

```
// binds a click event-handler to the '.links' element,
// which executes the function *if* that click took place
// on an <a> element:
$('.links').on('click', 'a', function () {
    // creates an <a> element, setting its 'href' to '#'
    // and its text to 'a new link'
    $('<a />', {
        'href' : '#',
        'text' : 'a new link'
    // then inserts it after the clicked <a> element:
    }).insertAfter(this);
});
```

Given the added details:

> I want it so that it will multiply the `<a href="#">#1</a>` but make the 1 a 2 and then 2 a 3 and so forth

The following should be more appropriate:

```
// binds the click event-handler to the .links element,
// executing the function if the click was initiated on
// (or within) an <a> element:
$('.links').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  // prevents the default action of the link:
  e.preventDefault();
  // caching a reference to the parentNode of the clicked-link:
  var parent = this.parentNode;

  // creating a new <a> element, setting its:
  $('<a />', {
    // text to the character '#' + the sum of the number of
    // children + 1:
    'text' : '#' + (parent.children.length + 1),
    // setting the href to '#':
    'href' : '#'
  // appending the created-<a> to the parent element:  
  }).appendTo(parent);
});
```

```js
$('.links').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var parent = this.parentNode;
  $('<a />', {
    'text' : '#' + (parent.children.length + 1),
    'href' : '#'
  }).appendTo(parent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">#1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: For this solution, make sure you are using jQuery `>= 1.7`. Otherwise, take a look at the method [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. I got stuck on this problem today and could not find the proper solution. I wanted to ask you though how did you learn javascript / jquery so well that you created your own solution instead of finding it like me?

Comment: I'm glad to have helped, and you're quite welcome! As for how did I learn JavaScript/jQuery? Basically: practice. I started with jQuery, asked a few questions on here and, almost accidentally, picked up JavaScript as I went; learning from other more-experienced users on this site that took the time, and were generous enough, to help me learn. It's easy for us - with more experience - to say that JavaScript is 'easy,' but it's only easy once you've spent time with it, and ideally had others willing to help you to learn. Try to learn, but have patience.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$('.links a').bind('click', function(){
    $('.links').append('<a href="#">#2</a>');
});
```

Comment: but then i want it so if I click on 2 it will become 3. how can I increment the numbers as well

Comment: As a note: While `.bind` is not wrong, I would us the `.on` in answers `[...] as of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.[...]`

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var linkNumber = 2;

  function addLink() {
      $('.links').append('<br/><a onclick=\"addLink()\" href=\"#\">#'+ linkNumber + '</a>');
      linkNumber++
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
  <a onclick="addLink()" href="#">#1</a>
</div>
```